# Primary key in Laravel model not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing an application in Laravel `5.2.27`. I have setup a model where primary key is other than `id` and I have defined primary key in my model by using:

`protected $primaryKey = 'district_code';`

When fetching the records the value of district code is displayed something else, different than that of record stored in database. But when I remove the line `protected $primaryKey = 'district_code';` everything works fine.

Comment: Check your MySQL DB, does that column has primary constraint on district_code?

Comment: Use `DB::getQueryLog()` and see what query is generated.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add in the model

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show/add your Table structure and Records which you are fetching?

another thing, did you defined table name in your model?
eg like this.

```
protected $table    =   'doseage_form';
```

Comment: I have defined the table name using `protected $table = 'districts';`.   The table structure is as below:                                                                        +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| district_code | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name          | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Comment: can you tell me which query you wrote, which causing issue ?